# Does anyone have the eigenvalue and eigenvectors for Alexnet's PCA noise from the imagenet dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, imagenet

Does anyone have the eigenvalue and eigenvectors for Alexnet's PCA noise from the imagenet dataset?

The imagenet dataset has 12million images and my computer is unable to calculate PCA for such a big image set. I am wondering if anyone has done it and can post the value for the eigenvalue and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
eigval = [55.46, 4.794, 1.148]
eigvec = [[-0.5675, 0.7192, 0.4009],[-0.5808, -0.0045, -0.8140],[-0.5836, -0.6948, 0.4203]]
```

Comment: how did you calculate this for such a long dataset ?